# MemoryStream->ToArray() returning null

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, encryption, aes, msdn

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES 128 CBC and I have been following the MSDN example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

but when I do:

```
encKey = msEncrypt->ToArray();
```

I have an array length of zero when debugging. Why isn't the encKey array filled with encrypted output?
Implementation Code:

```
ICryptoTransform^ encryptor = encAES->CreateEncryptor();
MemoryStream^ msEncrypt = gcnew MemoryStream();
CryptoStream^ csEncrypt = gcnew CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode::Write);
StreamWriter^ swEncrypt = gcnew StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
swEncrypt->Write(publicKey);
encKey = msEncrypt->ToArray();
```

Thanks for any help.

Solution:

```
    ICryptoTransform^ encryptor = encAES->CreateEncryptor();
    MemoryStream^ msEncrypt = gcnew MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream^ csEncrypt = gcnew CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode::Write);
    StreamWriter^ swEncrypt = gcnew StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
    swEncrypt->Write(publicKey);
    swEncrypt->Close();
    csEncrypt->Close();
    encKey = msEncrypt->ToArray();
    msEncrypt->Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to [flush the final block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx).

Block cipher modes normally require a full block to be written. The last block contains the padding, and the implementation only adds the padding to the plain text when it has received the last byte of plaintext. It cannot determine if there is any data coming in after `Write`, so it won't pad. Therefore the last - and probably only - block of ciphertext is not written.

Just flushing won't work, as that only makes sure as many bytes are written to the output stream as possible. But those bytes may not be the last bytes. Closing the output stream  should work as well, as the stream can then determine that the last bytes have been written.

Comment: Hi, carbon, did you resolve the issue after reading my answer?

Comment: I believe it did! Thank you, I wonder why the example didn't include the flush.
edit: sorry I can't upvote you.

Comment: I replaced `swEncrypt->Flush()` with `swEncrypt->Close()` before `encKey = msEncrypt->ToArray()` seems like Flush wasn't writing the padding information.

Comment: @carbon I'll adjust the answer, the link points to the right "final" flush method, but that isn't clear. Closing the stream undoubtedly also calls this method. If you only flush then the output stream still expects more bytes, hence it cannot yet pad...